# Dell Inspiron 1545 screen not working but external vga working

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have a dell inspiron 1545 and changed the screen recently. It started making a crackling noise then after a while screen stopped working. I plugged an external monitor & it didn't work. I removed the lcd and external monitor works. I thought it was the screen so I tried a few (which I know work) but same problem, nothing on the lcd and when I disconnect lcd / external screen, but when lcd is disconnected external screen works fine. Please help

Comment: So, when you disconnect the ribbon cable to your laptop's LCD then the external monitor works. If you connect the ribbon cable to your laptops LCD then the external monitor doesn't work? And either way, the laptop LCD doesn't work. Is this correct?

Comment: When a monitor starts to make a noise its beyond your ability to repair it. You will need to send it to Dell for repair or purchase a replacement unit by purchasing a used laptop of the same model.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your response. You are correct. The external monitor only works when the ribbon cable is not attached